# On mobile, best practice for font-size with 'width=device-width'?

Tags: html, css, mobile

On a mobile website, what is the best way to size text while also taking advantage of the `width=device-width` viewport setting?

Comment: Rem, but it's not fully supported by all browsers yet (i.e. IE).

Comment: 'IE 9 & IE 10 do not support rem units when used in the font shorthand property (the entire declaration is ignored) or when used on pseudo elements.' [source](http://caniuse.com/#search=rem)

Comment: @Aibrean Nice to hear about rem, yeah it's problematic that it isn't widely supported yet.. but I am curious, if I'd use rem, what unit should I use for the base font size?

Answer (score 0):

How about the percent for style? Like 100% or 90%.

Comment: Percent of what? what would be the base font size? I'd love to know if I'm missing anything

Answer (score 0):

I like to use vw because it zooms really well on tablets. You'll need to use multiple media queries for phones/tablets, though.

Comment: It's great from my experience but not supported enough from my experience (at least on native mobile browsers)